# Рекурсия и счетчик

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу посчитать, сколько раз делается операция "вычитание" в рекурсии. Подумал, просто сделать как дополнительный аргумент это сам счетчик и в возврат постоянно добавлять по 1. Это правильный подход ? Или лучше сделать какой то метод дополнительный который это делает ?

```
def f(k, count = 0):
    if k<3:
        print(count)
        return 1
    return f(k-1, count+1)+f(k-2, count+1)+f(k-3, count+1)
```

Comment: Гм... а просто попробовать? Для начала - попробовать менять дефолтное значение переменной `count`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Хочу посчитать, сколько раз делается операция "вычитание" в рекурсии*

Вы конечно, что-то считаете, но как достать результат, если вы хотите общую сумму, из вашего кода не очевидно. Я бы сделал так

```
count = 0

def f(k):
    global count
    count += 1
    if k<3:
        return 1
    return f(k-1)+f(k-2)+f(k-3)

f(5)
print(count) # 13
```

Comment: Можно не глобальную переменную делать, а например, через список `count = [0]`, а внутри функции `count[0] += 1`

Comment: Да, можно так. я просто, чтоб очевидней было

Comment: @gil9red, это все еще будет использованием глобальной переменной, несмотря на отсутствие ключевого слова `global`. Лучше уж как сейчас ("явное лучше неявного").

Comment: @insolor, если тот `count = [0]` передавать вторым параметром, это не будет глобальным использованием :)

Answer (score 3):

Количество вычитаний (если речь о вычитании в `k-1` и т.д.) можно посчитать с помощью похожей рекуррентной формулы

> X<sub>0</sub> = 0
>   X<sub>1</sub> = 0
>   X<sub>2</sub> = 0
>   X<sub>k</sub> = X<sub>k-1</sub> + X<sub>k-2</sub> + X<sub>k-3</sub> + 3

Для `k < 3` вычитания не требуются, а для больших `k`, кроме всех вычитаний в рекурсивных вызовах, потребуется еще 3

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def g(k):
    return 0 if k < 3 else g(k - 1) + g(k - 2) + g(k - 3) + 3

print(g(100)) # 190607426830504128224152470
```

Также можно объединить оба вычисления в одно

```
@functools.lru_cache(None)
def h(k):
    if k < 3:
        return 1, 0
    else:
        a1, b1 = h(k - 1)
        a2, b2 = h(k - 2)
        a3, b3 = h(k - 3)
        return a1 + a2 + a3, b1 + b2 + b3 + 3

print(h(100)) # (127071617887002752149434981, 190607426830504128224152470)
```